# DataContext and Caliburn

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

As I understand I'm not even supposed to initialize the `DataContext` in XAML explicitly when using Caliburn.Micro to make bindings work properly.

But if I will not, then the standard parser will say that the bindings are invalid as far as we can't rely on conventions in all situations.

How to set up `DataContext` properly using View-Model first approach with Caliburn.Micro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caliburn.Micro automatically creates the view-model and sets it as the `DataContext` of the view by convention.

For example if you have a view-model called `MainViewModel` and a view named `MainView`, then Caliburn.Micro will automatically create `MainViewModel` and then create `MainView` and then set `MainViewModel` as `DataContext` of `MainView`.

So even if you use binding that don't rely on conventions they would still work because the `DataContext` is set automatically by Caliburn.Micro`.

You can read all about this and more in [Caliburn.Micro's Documentation](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/documentation).

Comment: Agreeing with Sniffer, this is part of the basics of Caliburn.Micro, I encourage you to take your time to read the documentation and the examples :-)

Comment: Thank you, but as I said, if we don't set the DataContext explicitly, then the standard Visual Studios' xaml parser will exlaim that the bindings can't be resolved. This is very irritating.

Comment: Besides, what about design-time data binding? Are we able to not declare DataContext in View's xaml explicitly in this scenario?

Comment: @EngineerSpock If you are talking about design-time visual studio complaining or design-time support. Caliburn.Micro supports both scenarios, please take a look at the documentation and here is the link for [design-time support](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Design-Time%20Support&referringTitle=Documentation).